# Get JSON child element value

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to get `spuCode` from this JSON:

```
{
  "msg": "success",
  "state": 0,
  "data": {
    "result": {
      "spuCode": "541426110605",
      "productName": "纯黑色斜纹面料铅笔裤百搭大码小脚裤弹力打底裤休闲裤子女",
      "productTitle": null,
      "spuImgs": [
        "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2016/276/468/3618864672_1742354982.jpg",
        "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2016/793/372/3617273397_1742354982.jpg",
        "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2016/726/552/3617255627_1742354982.jpg",
        "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2017/521/101/4624101125_1742354982.jpg",
        "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/2017/070/749/4580947070_1742354982.jpg"
      ],
      "upAndDown": 1,
      "updateTime": 1537096913958,
      "platform": "ALIBABA",
      "skus": [
        {
          "skuCode": "3488434133172",
          "sellPrice": 3900,
          "sellableNum": 905,
          "productProps": [
            {
              "propId": 7590793702270582000,
              "valueId": 5453504708925905000,
              "propName": "颜色",
              "valueName": "纯黑色（相同面料）"
            },
            {
              "propId": 9000005669393888000,
              "valueId": 6217370164147047000,
              "propName": "尺码",
              "valueName": "XXL"
            }
          ],
```

As you can see there is Parent `data` with child `result` so I added this code:

```
string sp = "";
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);
foreach (JObject child in obj["data"]["result"].OfType<JObject>())
{
    sp = child["spuCode"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(sp);
}
```

But it never triggers `MessageBox.Show` what am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe the result is _not_ of type [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)? Try debugging and see by yourself.

Comment: I would try casting it to [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) instead of `JObject`. But as said above, debugging the whole thing is _way_ better than any guessing.

Comment: your json is not valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` isn't an array so there is no need for `foreach`.

Try `SelectToken` method like this:

```
var spuCode = (string)obj.SelectToken("data.result.spuCode");
```